# How to access Google cloud library in python3 standard app engine project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use the datastore in the google cloud sdk.

When I try and import:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
```

I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

But I do have the google cloud sdk installed and it's available in my lib directory:

[image]

The problem seems to be that when I try and import it another google folder is used:

[image]

Edit:
After running `pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore` I can now import google.cloud from the command line but it still does not work in my project.

What next steps can I take to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the issue that you got. If we follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) then indeed it doesn't work. However, if you run `pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore` then it does the trick.

Comment: Running the upgrade got the "from google.cloud import datastore" statement to work on my command line. But in my app it still fails. Any idea why?

Comment: Where are you deploying your app? on App Engine?

Comment: Yes, on app engine. But I'm currently running the app locally by running "dev_appserver.py app.yaml". The import statement fails within this local environment, whereas now it does work on the command line outside of the project.

Comment: Without having access to your code, it might be that you don't have the datastore in your requirements.txt. If you haven't done already, you can add google-cloud-datastore==1.7.3 in it and it might fix it. If you have done this already, please edit your question with some minimum reproducible code so that we can investigate it further

Comment: Aahh... So I have to always add all my dependencies to requirements.txt before running locally. Did not know that, I'm quite new to python. Adding it to the requirements fixed it. I will accept your answer!